# Put phone app back on dock in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, dock

I accidentally removed the Apple Phone app from the dock.

Now I cannot locate the *Phone* app icon, so I cannot drag it back to the dock. Too many apps, too many folders.

I asked Siri to show me the *Phone* app. But she insists on *launching* the app rather than *showing* me the app icon.

How can I get the lost app icon back on the dock.

Comment: You should try **Settings > General > Reset > Reset Home Screen Layout** and see if that brings it back. That's the general remedy for restoring a deleted Apple iOS default app.

Comment: @IconDaemon Doesn’t *Settings > General > Reset > Reset Home Screen Layout* destroy all my custom folders?

Comment: @BasilBourque Is Siri able to launch the Phone app for you?

Comment: @NimeshNeema Yes. And if scrolling to the last page of the Home Screen, with Apple's automatic folders, I can see the Phone app icon. But tapping and holding only offers actions. No way to enter "jiggle-mode" with dancing icons to drag to dock.

Comment: @BasilBourque Tapping and holding an app icon in App Library would not show the icons in "jiggle-mode". What are the options that you see in the context menu? If you don't see the option titled "Add to Home Screen", the Phone app icon is still present in one of the Home Screens.

Answer (score 2):

You may have accidentally deleted the Phone app icon from the Home Screen.

[image: Remove app icon from Home Screen in iOS]

iOS does not allow you to uninstall the Phone app, so the app is still installed on your iPhone, with the app icon visible in the App Library.

You can get the Phone app icon back in the Home Screen using the following steps:

1. Keep swiping Left on your Home Screen until you see the App Library.
2. Locate the Phone app within the App Library. Use the search bar shown at the top if you have too many apps installed and are unable to locate the Phone app.

   [image: Searching app in iOS App Library]
3. Now touch and hold on the Phone app icon and select the **Add to Home Screen** option in the app icon's context menu.

   [image: iOS App Library app icon Touch and hold context menu]
4. The Phone app icon would be added in your Home Screen.
5. Now tap and hold in any empty area on your Home Screen until the icons start wiggling.
6. Drag the Phone icon and put it in the Dock.

You can find an easy to follow demonstration of the above in the official Apple Support video on YouTube:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=53eOAsqGQC0

On the other hand, if you have not deleted the Phone app icon from the Home Screen, but merely *moved* it from the Dock, you'd need to locate it among one of the Home Screen pages or folders therein.

In either case, you should be able to see the Phone app icon in the App Library. If the Phone app icon's context menu in the App Library doesn't give you the Add to Home Screen option, it's buried somewhere in one of the Home Screens.

Comment: #2 is the catch. Cannot find that icon, as mentioned in my second paragraph. Too many apps, too many folders.

Comment: @BasilBourque Try using the Spotlight search in the App Library to locate the Phone app.